# A simple function returning value in one schema but not is other schema

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, database-schema

I have a simple basic function which is running fine and returning some value in HR schema. But when I am running the same function in other schema scott then it is not returning anything.

1)What will be the possible reason for not returning the value.
2)How to fix the issue in scott schema itself.

Comment: Please provide the function you are using and the way you are returning the value

Comment: How do you expect people to debug code they cannot see?

Comment: @EdStevens:I know buddy but what can I do , if interviewer asked me questions like that only. I need to prepare for such questions, so that I can answer them next time.

Comment: You should have said it was an interview question.  Here's how I'd deal with it in that situation. First, I don't treat interviews like a fill-in-the-blank test.  I treat them like two-way conversations. Second, in a good interview, some questions are not to see if you can 'fill in the blank' but to see how you go about problem solving.  In this case, I'd ask the interviewer exactly what I asked you ... how can you expect to debug code you cannot see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As HR and SCOTT schema don't contain same tables nor data, a function that "works" in one doesn't necessarily work in another.

2) By debugging the function, finding what causes the problem and fixing it. Can we help? Nope, as we can't debug code we can't see.